# c make a copy of an array of const structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, copy, constants

I have an array of structs and some of the struct members are constant
I would like to make a deep copy of the array.
The copy will also have the same members of the struct be constants.
How do I initialize the values into the new array without violating the *const* directive.

Below is an excerpt of my code.  The actual program is quite long but I think I've included all the relevant code.  In this example *keys* is declared as a global variable that I would like to make new instances from.  I'm treating it sort of like a template with preset values.

When I try to compile this in Debian with gcc I get the following error:

```
main.c:216:9: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*(new_keys + (unsigned int)((unsigned int)index * 540u))’make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

The makefile is using the following qualifier:

```
CFLAGS=-c -g -std=gnu99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700
```

Interestingly.  I can compile the same code in Xcode without an error or warning even with Xcode set for C Language Dialect GNU99[-std=gnu99]

I can make my code work simply by getting rid of the const keywords.  But these values truly should be const.  Once these arrays are initialized they will never change.  I would like to understand how to do this properly and also I would like to know why this works in Xcode and not gcc.

Header File

```
typedef struct {
    char * name;
    char * alias;
    int number;
} pair_int_t;

typedef struct {
    const char * const name;
    const kind_t kind; // kind is enum type
    const pair_int_t * const enum_array; 
    bool received; 
    const char * const alias; 
} key_descriptor_t;

typedef key_descriptor_t keys_descriptor_t[_END_OF_KEYS+1];
```

body of .c program before main()

```
const pair_int_t command_list[] = {
    {.name = "numeric data response",        .alias = "num",         .number = RES_NUMERIC_DATA},
    {.name = "read attribute",               .alias = "readat",      .number = CMD_READ_ATTR},
    //..
}

// declare a global variable *keys* with constants assigned to it
key_descriptor_t keys[] = {
    [_COMMAND]          = {.name = "command",           .kind = ENUMERATED, .alias = "com",    .enum_array = command_list},
    [_RESPONSE]         = {.name = "response",          .kind = ENUMERATED, .alias = "res",    .enum_array = command_list},
    [_UNIT]             = {.name = "unit number",       .kind = NUMBER,     .alias = "uni",    .enum_array = NULL},
//..
}

int initialize_new_keys(keys_descriptor_t new_keys) {
    int index;
    for (index = _FIRST_KEY; index <= _END_OF_KEYS; index++){
        new_keys[index] = keys[index];      // line 216, keys is a global variable  
    }
    return index;
}
```

main program

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    keys_descriptor_t 2nd_set_of_keys;
    initialize_new_keys(2nd_set_of_keys);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only initialize `const` variables at the time you define them. Creating an array with `const` members, sending it to a function, and then trying to assign to those members signifies that you didn't really mean `const` in the first place. There's no syntax in C for "`const` except for the first assignment".

A reasonable alternative is to make an opaque type, encapsulate the definition in a separate translation unit, and then access all the members purely through an interface of functions. That way, even though things may not be `const`, they still can't be changed (except through deliberate subversion, which is at least no better than not calling things `const` in the first place) because no code that uses them has access to the definition of the `struct`, or therefore to the members.

EDIT: In response to the question in the comment, "is there a way to create and initialize one complex constant variable to the value of another existing constant variable of the same type?", there sure is - just initialize it normally:

```
struct mystruct {
    const int a;
    const int b;
};

static const struct mystruct m = {1, 2};

int main(void) {
    struct mystruct n = m;
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously the more complex your `struct` is, the more complex this may become.

Comment: I thought that where I have placed `const` in the definition of my struct would make the member of the struct constant no the entire struct its self.  So when I make the assignment `new_keys[index] = keys[index];`  I thought I was making a copy of a non-const struct with some const members and placing it in a non-const member of an array.  Is the error that I'm getting in gcc actually mean that I'm violating the `const` property?  What is the 540u portion of the error?

Comment: The problem is your `struct` members get created when your overall `struct` gets created (they have to, otherwise "creating the `struct`" wouldn't really have any meaning), so as soon as you create your `struct` you already have your `const` members, and if you didn't initialize them at the time of creation, you've lost your chance to do so. The `540u` is just an unsigned integer equal to 540, it's just gcc doing pointer arithmetic on your array. Yes, the problem here is violating `const`.

Comment: @TimothyVann the error message is strange but the error is certainly that you are attempting to write to a const location

Comment: So when I make the assignment `= keys[index]` (which evaluates to a struct), I'm copying the values from the existing struct at keys[index] into the other existing struct at new_keys[index] which was initialized when I created the array with `keys_descriptor_t 2nd_set_of_keys;`?  Is that correct?

Comment: Why would Xcode using gnu99 allow this while gcc not allow it?

Comment: @TimothyVann: Correct, except it wasn't *initialized* when you created it (at least not explicitly so) because you did not, in fact, initialize it with any values when you created it. You effectively end up with `const` members containing uninitialized garbage that you now cannot change. As for "Xcode", you have to be careful, since Xcode is an IDE and doesn't compile anything - you probably mean clang. I have no idea what's happening there, other than compilers are allowed to compile bad code if they want to, particularly when you explicitly turn off a standards-compliance mode.

Comment: Is there a way to create and initialize one complex constant variable to the value of another existing constant variable of the same type?

Comment: @TimothyVann Not sure what you mean by "complex". You can write `T a = b;` if `T` is not an array type. It seems to me you're best off just not making your structs have `const` members.

Comment: @TimothyVann: There sure is, see edit to the answer. But I concur with Matt that `const` seems to be creating more problems than it's solving, here.

Comment: Just to make sure I have this 100% correct.  @Matt McNabb said _"You can write `T a = b;` if `T` is not an array type."_  - If `T` is an array type with constant members that this can not be done at all?

Comment: You can to use a brace-enclosed initializer to initialize the array, e.g. `T x[20] = { [3] = b, [4] = c, ` etc. but you can't specify in one go that these 20 elements be initialized from those 20 elements of another array

Comment: Thank you very much.  That was very helpful.  I really appreciate that people like you take the time to answer these newbee questions.

Answer (score 0):

"2nd_set_of_keys" is a struct, it should be a static array (or can be a pointer and reserve memory dynamically), the same problem occurs with the "new_keys" parameter.
Although a little weird, you can copy data to const variables (overriding the const verification) by using memcpy().