# Trying to copy a string into a const char * array in C

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, declaration, c-strings

I am trying to convert a string in C (using the string.h library) into a const char array.

```
int len = sizeof(the_string);
const char *char_array = malloc(len);
strcpy(char_array, the_string);
```

I have pored through the string.h method file and googled it but things keep coming up in C++. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!!

Comment: You might revisit your learning material about the meaning of `const` keyword. You cannot copy anything into a variable declared as `const`. That is exactly what `const` is about. You can also not pass a pointer to a `const` area into `free`.

Comment: As has been stated before, `const` essentially tells the compiler 'content must not be modified', which is why this assignment fails. May I ask why you insist on `const char` there? Please note, that the compiler automatically converts to `const *`, but not back. (So calling a function which takes `const char *` with a `const *` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c make a copy of an array of const structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902711/c-make-a-copy-of-an-array-of-const-structs)

Comment: What part of the error message you get do you need help with understanding?

Comment: You won't get the length of string using `sizef()` operator. The `sizeof()` operator will give you the size of structures in number of bytes. Use `strlen()` funciton instead.

Comment: @Kozmotronik: ignoring `const`, if `the_string` is defined using `char the_string[] = "the string's value";` (as an array), then `sizeof(the_string)` is fine and includes the null byte in the count.  If it is defined using `char *the_string = "the string's value";`, then using `sizeof(the_string)` is wrong — it returns the size of the pointer, not the length of the string that the pointer points at.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how can we know that how `the_string` is defined if it is not included in the code? Which is better; giving solution based on guess or giving a solution that will work in any way? What will happen if the definition is like this `const char *the_string = "Some string";`? Whoops the malloc will allocate only the size of pointer. So what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: @Kozmotronik: In your _comment_ (not an answer), you say "you won't get the length of the string using the `sizeof` operator" — a blanket statement that denies the possibility of a circumstance where using `sizeof` will work.  I gave a counter-example where it will work.  You're right that we don't know how the string is defined, and `strlen()` will always work, but `sizeof` will also work sometimes, albeit not very often.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration of a pointer

```
const char *char_array;
```

means that you may not change the memory pointed to by the pointer using the pointer.

You could make the pointer itself a constant object like

```
char * const char_array = malloc( some_size );
```

In this case you may not reassign the pointer itself but you may change the memory pointed to by the pointer.

Take into account that the expression `sizeof(the_string)` does not make a great sense if you are going to know the length of a string stored in a character array because in general a character array can be much larger than the stored string in it. Instead you should write

```
size_t len = strlen( the_string );
```

Using the expression sizeof(the_string) makes a sense in declarations such this

```
char the_string[] = "Hello";
```

that is when the size of a character array is determined by the size of a string literal used as an initializer.

Comment: The definition of `the_string` is not shown in the question.  If it is an array (`const char the_string[] = "the value in the string";`) then `sizeof(the_string)` correctly reports the size of the array including the terminal null byte and all is OK.  If it is defined as `const char *the_string = "the value of the string";` then `sizeof(the_string)` gives completely the wrong answer.  Using `size_t len = strlen(the_string) + 1;` gives the correct size whichever way `the_string` is defined, so it is best — but the `+ 1` is crucial!